# Recreate function signature and call via template packs in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I have C code that I want to rewrite in C++. The C code is part of a interpreter where the functions are defined in C however the actual call is from the interpreted source. Basically what it does is listed below:

```
#include <vector>

void f1(int a0) { }
void f2(int a0,int a1) { }
void f3(int a0,int a1,int a2) { }
void f4(int a0,int a1,int a2,int a3) { }

struct m {
    void *p;
    int c;
};

std::vector<m> ma;

int addfunc(void *p, int c) {
    int i = ma.size();
    ma.push_back({p,c});
    return i;
}

void call(int idx, int *stack) {
    switch (ma[idx].c) {
    case 1:
    ((void (*)(int))ma[idx].p)  (stack[0]);
    break;
    case 2:
    ((void (*)(int,int))ma[idx].p)  (stack[0],stack[1]);
    break;
    case 3:
    ((void (*)(int,int,int))ma[idx].p)  (stack[0],stack[1],stack[2]);
    break;
    case 4:
    ((void (*)(int,int,int,int))ma[idx].p)  (stack[0],stack[1],stack[2],stack[3]);
    break;
    }
}

int main (void) {
    int stack[5] = { 0,1,2,3,4 };
    /* define */
    int i1 = addfunc((void*)f1, 1);
    int i2 = addfunc((void*)f2, 2);
    int i3 = addfunc((void*)f3, 3);
    int i4 = addfunc((void*)f4, 4);
    /* call */
    call(i1,stack);
    call(i2,stack);
    call(i3,stack);
    call(i4,stack);
}
```

The `addfunc` creates a callable object specified by a function pointer and a signature, because the arguments are of the same type int only a count argument for the number of arguments is needed.
When I `call` a function I specify the function object's index and  a `stack`. The actual c-call is decoded via the argument count and typecasted, the call arguments are taken from the stack.

How can I rewrite the `addfunc` and `call` functions as templates objects in C++? How can I use template packs to count the number of arguments for the given function and regenerate the call to the function? 
**How can I get rid of the switch statement and the function pointer typecast**? I have seen that [luawrapper](https://github.com/tomaka/luawrapper/blob/73a345f5079e3b4d7e5545e55fffcdae68082bef/include/LuaContext.hpp#L1673)'s `Binder` class does something similar. However the code is quite complicated. In my case the arguments are all of the same type.
In the end I want to do something like (pseudocode):

```
vector<meth> ma;
...
int i0 = addfunc([](int a) { });
int i1 = addfunc([](int a,int b) { });
int i2 = addfunc([](int a,int b,int b) { });
int i3 = addfunc([](int a,int b,int c,int c) { });
...
ma[i0](stack);
ma[i1](stack);
ma[i2](stack);
ma[i3](stack);
```

Comment: I... don't really get it. `addfunc` returns an integer, but then you pass that integer directly to `call`? What's the point of using overloads, then? What are you really trying to achieve here?  Just call functions of different arities with one list of ints?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz : The integer is standing for the "function object" created. The main question is howto get rid of the switch statement and the function typecast.

Comment: you cannot translate code literally line by line. Currently its not completely clear what the code is supposed to do. In C++ you dont have to work around the absence of overloading (because c++ has overloading ;)

Comment: @user463035818 : The call construct is part of a Interpreter. The functions to call are defined in C however the actuall call is from the Interpreted code.

Comment: If that's for the Lua code, there are way better solutions than that.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz : No, it is not Lua code. It is a simple Interpreted language, when evaluating I use this constructs to call into the atomic c functions.

Comment: @KonradEisele and are those plain C functions that can be converted to function pointers?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz : basically the f1-f4 functions represent plain c functions. The argument types are uniform. however I dont need the function name, thats why I  write lambdas instead  in the c++ pseudocode.

Comment: intriguing question... which version of the standard do you accept? C++98? C++11? C++14? C++17?

Comment: @max66 : c++17 is acceptable

Comment: @KonradEisele If the cpp version has to do exactly what the c does, there is not much improvements that can be done. If there is more information available in compile time like list of functions or size of stack, then cpp can do better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if they're just C functions, why not overload on the function pointer type?

```
std::function<void(std::array<int, 5>)> addfunc(void (*f)(int)) {
    return [f](std::array<int, 5> const& a) { f(a[0]); };
}

std::function<void(std::array<int, 5>)> addfunc(void (*f)(int,int)) {
    return [f](std::array<int, 5> const& a) { f(a[0], a[1]); };
}

// repeat for all necessary arities
```

Then create `std::vector<std::function<void(std::array<int, 5>)>>` and push back all your functions. It's easy, doesn't require any templates and will work reasonably well. It introduces the overhead of `std::function`, though.

You could get rid of that by introducing your own callable type (n of them), that would correspond to the overloads above, provide an `operator()` and store appropriate function type inside.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f78b99d554a90da).

Comment: On top of your answer: Is there a way of defining the different variants via variadic templates?

Comment: @KonradEisele: Something like [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/609e5ad061b751f8)

Comment: @Jarod42: Exactly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you won't be able to make a completely generic solution, as there is no way to type-erase arity.

One way you can simplify things would be to create a set of wrappers for your functions, each wrapper accepting a `stack*`, and calling implementation functions with arguments from said `stack`.

Than you do not need typecasts at all and a simple function pointer (to approriate wrapper) would do (no even need to type-erase).

Comment: "there is no way to type-erase arity" iirc i wrote something in this direction some time ago. I was storing arbitrary lambdas to be called later with the correct number of user supplied parameters. unfortunately i dont have the code here...

Comment: The link I posted (https://github.com/tomaka/luawrapper/blob/73a345f5079e3b4d7e5545e55fffcdae68082bef/include/LuaContext.hpp#L1673) seems to use some template pack magic. Somehow it is too complicated for me to really grasp, but in some way it seem possible...

Comment: You can type-erase arity using [variadic functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic), but that is not type-safe at all.

Comment: @HenriMenke only if original function signature actually accepts variadic.

Comment: @KonradEisele, no template pack magic can work with type-erased run-time arity. Your link is calling a function with arity set at compile time.

Comment: @SergeyA : But that is the case with my code too. The functions that are called in the end are c functions who's signature is known at compile time when calling addfunc .

Comment: Yes, but it is not known at call site, as far as I can tell?

Comment: @SergeyA : There is some way to do this via variadic templates as for https://github.com/tomaka/luawrapper/blob/73a345f5079e3b4d7e5545e55fffcdae68082bef/include/LuaContext.hpp#L1673 does it. But I didn't yet figure out how it is done.

Comment: @KonradEisele you misunderstand what the binder does. It doesn't type-erase at all. It can bind a function and a first parameter. But the number of arguments to function is determined at the call site. You will call `operator()` of the binder object with N arguments - it is going to call the bound function with the same N arguments.

Comment: @SergeyA : I'm not completely understanding luwrapper but: Binder()  is used by readIntoFunction () that is called by callback2() in LuaContext::Pusher<TReturnType (TParameters...)> which is defined by templating when defining the function (much like the addfunc in my case). Then you call it at runtime everything is setup so that stack arguments are picked and the c function called with the right amount of arguments... But I'm not shure. It would also be intereting to see what the overhead is...

Answer (score 1):

I propose a C++17 solution (simplified following a Jarod42's observation: thanks) that I suppose is over-complicated.

But I find it funny...

First: a struct that, given (as template parameters) a type and a unsigned number, define a `type` as the type received.

```
template <typename T, std::size_t>
struct getType
 { using type = T; };
```

It's used to convert a variadic template list of numbers in a sequence of types (`int`s, in the following example) of the same length.

Next: a template type that register (`setFunc()`) and exec (`callFunc()`) a function returning `void` and a sequence of `int`s length as the first template parameter.

```
template <std::size_t N, typename = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
struct frHelper;

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t ... Is>
struct frHelper<N, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
 {
   using fnPnt_t = void(*)(typename getType<int, Is>::type...);

   fnPnt_t fp = nullptr;

   void setFunc (fnPnt_t fp0)
    { fp = fp0; }

   void callFunc (std::array<int, sizeof...(Is)> const & a)
    { if ( fp ) fp(a[Is]...); }
 };
```

Last: a template struct that inherit from a variadic list of preceding structs and enable (`using`) the `setFunc()` and the `callFunc()` members.

```
template <std::size_t N, typename = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
struct funcRegister;

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t ... Is>
struct funcRegister<N, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
   : public frHelper<Is>...
 { 
   using frHelper<Is>::setFunc...;
   using frHelper<Is>::callFunc...;
 };
```

Use.

First you have to declare an object of type `funcRegister<N>` where `N` is the max number of integer received from your functions plus one. So if you want to use `f4()`, so four integers, you have to declare

```
   funcRegister<5u>  fr;
```

Then you have to register the functions

```
   fr.setFunc(f1);
   fr.setFunc(f2);
   fr.setFunc(f3);
   fr.setFunc(f4);
```

and, given some `std::array<int, N>` of the right size, you can call the registered functions

```
   std::array a1 { 1 };
   std::array a2 { 1, 2 };
   std::array a3 { 1, 2, 3 };
   std::array a4 { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

   fr.callFunc(a1); // call f1
   fr.callFunc(a2); // call f2
   fr.callFunc(a3); // call f3
   fr.callFunc(a4); // call f4
```

The following is a full compiling C++17 example

```
#include <array>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, std::size_t>
struct getType
 { using type = T; };

template <std::size_t N, typename = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
struct frHelper;

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t ... Is>
struct frHelper<N, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
 {
   using fnPnt_t = void(*)(typename getType<int, Is>::type...);

   fnPnt_t fp = nullptr;

   void setFunc (fnPnt_t fp0)
    { fp = fp0; }

   void callFunc (std::array<int, sizeof...(Is)> const & a)
    { if ( fp ) fp(a[Is]...); }
 };

template <std::size_t N, typename = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
struct funcRegister;

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t ... Is>
struct funcRegister<N, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
   : public frHelper<Is>...
 { 
   using frHelper<Is>::setFunc...;
   using frHelper<Is>::callFunc...;
 };

void f1(int) { std::cout << "f1 called" << std::endl; }
void f2(int,int) { std::cout << "f2 called" << std::endl;}
void f3(int,int,int) { std::cout << "f3 called" << std::endl;}
void f4(int,int,int,int) { std::cout << "f4 called" << std::endl;}

int main()
 {
   funcRegister<5u> fr;

   fr.setFunc(f1);
   fr.setFunc(f2);
   fr.setFunc(f3);
   fr.setFunc(f4);

   std::array a1 { 1 };
   std::array a2 { 1, 2 };
   std::array a3 { 1, 2, 3 };
   std::array a4 { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

   fr.callFunc(a1);
   fr.callFunc(a2);
   fr.callFunc(a3);
   fr.callFunc(a4);    
 }
```

Comment: You still decide the arity of the callee at call site at compile time. In original example, arity was decided at run-time.

Comment: @SergeyA - not exactly equivalent, I admit. But there is a worse (IMHO) problem : my solution permit only a function of a specified arity; the original example permit to register multiple functions with the same arity.

Comment: `getIndSeq` is not needed, `std::make_index_sequence<N>` **is** an alias for `std::index_sequence` (even if most implementations on SO use (wrongly) inheritance).

Comment: @Jarod42 - I didn't know at all; I was convinced that `std::index_sequence` was a base class for `std::make_index_sequence`. I've over-complicated other answers for this reason. Thanks for pointing it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [luawrapper](https://github.com/tomaka/luawrapper/blob/73a345f5079e3b4d7e5545e55fffcdae68082bef/include/LuaContext.hpp#L1673)'s code extracted to be applied the above case. This is more for completion as for @Jerod42's [code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/609e5ad061b751f8) is preferable.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

template<typename T> struct tag {};

template<typename TFunctionObject, typename TFirstParamType>
struct Binder {
    TFunctionObject function;
    TFirstParamType param;

    template<typename... TParams>
    auto operator()(TParams&&... params)
    -> decltype(function(param, std::forward<TParams>(params)...))
    {
        return function(param, std::forward<TParams>(params)...);
    }
};

template<typename TCallback>
static void readIntoFunction(int *stack, TCallback&& callback)
{
    callback();
}
template<typename TCallback, typename TFirstType, typename... TTypes>
static void readIntoFunction(int *stack, TCallback&& callback, tag<TFirstType>, tag<TTypes>... othersTags)
{
    Binder<TCallback, const TFirstType&> binder{ callback, *stack };
    return readIntoFunction(++stack, binder, othersTags...);
}

/* decompose arguments */
template<typename TFunctionType, typename... TOtherParams>
std::function<void(int*)> _addfunc(TFunctionType f, tag<void (*)(TOtherParams...)>) {
    return std::function<void(int*)>([f](int *stack) {
        readIntoFunction(stack, f, tag<TOtherParams>{}...);
    });
}

template<typename TFunctionType>
std::function<void(int*)> addfunc(TFunctionType fn)
{
    typedef typename std::decay<TFunctionType>::type RealFuncSig;
    return _addfunc(std::move(fn), tag<RealFuncSig>{} );
}

void f1(int a0) { std::cout << a0 << std::endl; }
void f2(int a0, int a1) { std::cout << a0 << a1 << std::endl;  }

int main() {
    int stack[5] = { 0,1,2,3,4 };
    auto a0 = addfunc(&f1);
    auto a1 = addfunc(&f2);

    a0(stack);
    a1(stack);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use [std:function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) as the parameter of the addfun() and also [std::bind](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)

Comment: Not really an answer, also, `std::function` can't type-erase arity.

Comment: std::bind is interesting but I wonder how to use it in my case: Maybe nested binds where I std::bind each argument position with a function call that picks out the argument from the stack with a preset index.